# Snapping boundaries in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, polygon, intersection, snapping, administrative-boundaries

I have two polygons in PostGIS that have incongruities. One polygon (the yellow one) is legal county boundaries. The other polygon (blue) is essentially neighborhoods. 98% of the lines align perfectly. The other 2% don't align because the boundaries have changes but not been updated on the neighborhoods polygon.

My question: Using either PostGIS (preferred) or QGIS, how can I "snap" the neighborhood boundaries to the county boundaries? I've tried:

`ST_Multi(
      ST_Intersection(neighborhoods.geom, county.geom)
      ) END AS geom`

EDIT: This query "worked" in that it prevented neighborhoods from bleeding into incorrect counties, but it just removes the area that causes the bleed creating blank spaces inbetween boundaries.

[image: snap]

Comment: I would love to see anyone with a postgis solution as well.

Comment: For those who arrived here seeking a PostGIS solution, here's what I've arrived at:


SELECT b.block, p.county_name, p.district_id
ST_AREA(CASE WHEN ST_CoveredBy(b.geom, p.geom) THEN p.geom ELSE ST_Multi(ST_Intersection(b.geom, p.geom)) END) AS geom
FROM blocks b
INNER JOIN district p ON (ST_Intersects(b.geom, p.geom) AND NOT ST_Touches(b.geom,p.geom))

From there, I ranked the area column, accepted the top ranked area, and forced a p.county_name=b.county_name match. This is *not* an ideal solution because it's highly specific to my use case, but may provide help to others.